# How do I change the default wallpaper on my custom rom

Tags: android, operating-system, android-source, android-wallpaper

I am trying to create my own custom rom, and I want to change the default wallpaper. How can I change the **default wallpaper** on custom rom's. To be more exact, where are default wallpapers **generically** located in the source code of various rom's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most **custom roms** it can be found in:

`vendor/{SOME_CUSTOM_VENDOR_NAME}/overlay/common/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-nodpi/default_wallpaper.png`

**e.g.** LineageOS:

`vendor/lineage/overlay/common/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-nodpi/default_wallpaper.png`

**e.g.** HavocOS:

`vendor/havoc/overlay/common/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-nodpi/default_wallpaper.png`

For plain AOSP it is:

`frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-nodpi/default_wallpaper.png`

And it can also be in a Device Tree Overlay as well.

Comment: For LineageOS 14.1 the vendor name is "CM"

Answer (score 0):

The default wallpaper is usually found in

```
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-nodpi/default_wallpaper.png
```

But it can be overwritten by OEM overlays found in `device/vendor`.